# Optional method parameter in Java

Tags: java, optional-parameters

I have this function `httpGet()` which calls `http()`:

```
public static int httpGet(String url, StringBuilder response) throws IOException {
    return http(url,(http)->http.setRequestMethod("GET"), response);
}

private static int http(String url, httpMethod method, StringBuilder response) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    http.setReadTimeout(5000);
    method.doMethod(http);
    int status = 404;
    ......
    ......
    return status;
}
```

I want to add an additional parameter for `readTimeout`, which needs to be optional with a default value that will be used otherwise.

In this case `readTimeout` is set to 5000 for all the calls, but I want this specific call to be executed for longer timeouts.

**I think I need this new parameter to be optional as I don't want to change the implementations where this `http()` method has been called.**

This is how I call it:

```
Assert.assertEquals(HTTP_OK, httpGet(DEFAULT_BROWSCAP_ENDPOINT, result));
```

How can I implement a new optional parameter for `readTimeout`?

Comment: Java doesn't have default values like Python, C++, VBA, Delphi, and many languages. Create new constructors with the alternate signature.

Comment: You need to define a new method, (unfortunately?) java doesn't support optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have default values like Python, C++, VBA, Delphi, and many languages. Create new constructors with the alternate signature.

```
public static int httpGet(String url, StringBuilder response) throws IOException {
    return httpGet(URL, response, 5000)
}

public static int httpGet(String url, StringBuilder response, int readTimeout) throws IOException {
    return http(url,(http)->http.setRequestMethod("GET"), response, readTimeout);
}


private static int http(String url, httpMethod method, StringBuilder response) throws IOException {
    return http(url, method, response, 5000);
}

private static int http(String url, httpMethod method, StringBuilder response, int readTimeout) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    http.setReadTimeout(readTimeout;
    method.doMethod(http);
    int status = 404;
    ......
    ......
    return status;
}
```

Comment: I think there's no need to create two versions of the private `http()` method, right?

Comment: No need in having an unused constructor. I didn't know if there was other code that was dependent on the shorter constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create 2 versions of the `httpGet` method (one with the `readTimeout` parameter, and another one without it which will call the first version with a default value):

```
private static final long DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT = 5000;

public static int httpGet(String url, StringBuilder response) throws IOException {
    return httpGet(url, response, DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT);
}

public static int httpGet(String url, StringBuilder response, long readTimeout) throws IOException {
    return http(url,(http)->http.setRequestMethod("GET"), response, readTimeout);
}

private static int http(String url, httpMethod method, StringBuilder response, long readTimeout) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    http.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    method.doMethod(http);
    int status = 404;
    ......
    ......
    return status;
}
```

Now you can decide to provide the timeout

```
httpGet(DEFAULT_BROWSCAP_ENDPOINT, result, mytimeout)
```

or not

```
httpGet(DEFAULT_BROWSCAP_ENDPOINT, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the way this is done is by providing many different functions with different signatures that just assume a default value. This can be done by "chaining" a bunch of functions together, each specifying it's default value and calling the more detailed function. For example:

```
public void myFunctionWithALotOfArguments(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    // do stuff
}
public void myFunctionWithLessArguments(int a, int b, int c) {
    myFunctionWithALotOfArguments(a, b, c, 50);
}
public void myFunctionWithFewArguments(int a, int b) {
    myFunctionWithLessArguments(a, b, 25);
}
public void mySimplifiedFunction(int a) {
    myFunctionWithFewArguments(a, 9);
}
public void justGuessWhatToDo() {
    mySimplifiedFunction(42);
}
```